# Creating a Search Bar in HAML format

Tags: ruby, haml, erb

The tutorial code for this is ERB format but I am doing it in HAML.

The ERB code:

```
<%= form_tag search_movies_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-right", role: "search" do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control" %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

What I have in HAML now:

```
- if user_signed_in?
  = link_to current_user.name, edit_user_registration_path
  = link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
  = link_to "Selling", new_post_path, class: "button"
  = form_tag posts_path, :method => :get do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search] 
    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default"
- else 
  = link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path
  = link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path
  = link_to "Selling", new_post_path, class: "button" 
  = form_tag posts_path, :method => :get do
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search]
    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default"
```

But it does not work. Anyone know how to do it?

My search method looks like this:

```
def search
  if params[:search].present?
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
  else
    @posts = Post.all
  end
end
```

Comment: What "does not work"? It's not clear from your explanation what it's supposed to do, nor where the problem might be.

Comment: So in this project I implemented the searchkick gemfile and I have done all of the job except don' know how write the search form in haml. I believe the error is from this line of code: 
= form_tag posts_path, :method => :get do
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: HAML and HTML are a 1:1 mapping, it's just a different way of expressing exactly the same thing.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You've defined an action (presumably in `PostsController`) called `search`, but you're referencing `posts_path`, which will go to the `index` action. You need to either put your code into `index` or use `search_posts_path`.

Here's the equivalent HAML for the ERB you posted, using `search_posts_path` to hit the action you have defined:

```
= form_tag search_posts_path, method: :get, class: "navbar-form navbar-right", role: "search" do
  %p
    = text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: "form-control"
    = submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-default"
```